# Can I start ntp.service after boot?

Tags: linux-mint, systemd, startup, ntp, ntpd

I've had issues with ntp drastically increasing the startup time, and I am not the only one, see for example [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/881636/disabling-ntp-service-for-the-boot-since-it-takes-a-long-time). Since it is responsible for adjusting my system time, I see no important reason for it to be started immediately at boot.

How can I make it start after boot instead and still work as it is supposed to? I would appreciate a method that could also be applied to other services.

Comment: An opposing comment: if you start any time-sensitive services (e.g. databases), you actually want NTP started *earlier*.

Comment: In addition to Jeff Schaller's point, which is underscored by the number of systems that you will find _are_ dependent from correct system time, there's the fact that the very same point is made in the AskUbuntu Q&A that you read.  In that Q&A, moreover, they wholly miss the wood for the trees, and entirely fail to address the problem of _why_ this is happening, which the questioner only even touches upon as a question comment.  That, of course, was addressed on AskUbuntu _at least three years earlier_ at Q&As like https://askubuntu.com/questions/403616/ .

Comment: But I'm on a desktop and don't have any time-sensitive stuff. Ntp should only make small adjustments anyways or adjust to summertime, so I don't see why I'd need it at boot

Answer (score 0):

From the comments in a linked answer, it appears that the issue may be `ntpdate`.  Modern versions of `ntpd` include the functionality included in `ntpdate`.   I would remove `ntpdate` if it installed.

Check the startup logs to see if they provide any detail on what is happening in your case.

You may want to run `top` during startup.  This may provide insight into what is happening.

Answer (score -1):

Since systemd parallelizes services startups, you can simply append the `sleep` command at the beginning of your services.

Comment: Given one of the potential causes of this behaviour, addressed on AskUbuntu back in 2014, this is an entirely wrongheaded idea that only compounds the problem.